# Cropping Multiple Images

Tags: python, charts

I'm working on a project to crop 1000 images. I have created 1000 images using an algorithm, and am trying to crop them. Currently, they are all sitting in a folder with names that follow the same format - "image1", "image2", etc. I have tried using online tools to crop all of these images but it isn't working. I'm looking for an approach, whether using a free software to crop all of them at once or using python to crop these images and store them in a separate folder. Any guidance will help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the Python library OpenCV.

```
import cv2
import glob

images = glob.glob(<path_to_image_directory>*jpg)

for img in images:
    img = cv2.imread(img)
    cropped_img = img[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
    cv2.imwrite(<filename>, cropped_img)
```